# vue 3 check if there is an event initialization

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuejs3

I use vue 3 and **srcipt setup**.

How i can check if there is an event initialization?

```
<Mycomp @search="load"
```

I try with $attr but @search miss

in 'Mycomp.vue':

```
import { useAttrs } from 'vue'
const attrs = useAttrs();
console.log(attrs);
```

[image]

Comment: If you have it defined in `defineEmits` It seems that this is intentional https://github.com/vuejs/core/issues/4706
However, I would also like to have a method to check if the event is being listened to, even having defined it in `defineEmits()`